# Why add shadow to any layer is too heavy? Using QuartzCore

Tags: objective-c, uiview, shadow, quartz-core

Why add shadow to any layer is too heavy?

I tried to add a shadow to my UIView and it was VERY heavy on this screen only.

Why is it so heavy? The only solution I find is to add a shadow image in PNG to simulate, is lighter than create a shadow using QuartzCore.

Is there any solution lighter for this?

Comment: What do you mean heavy? I doubt the phone gains mass. I assume you mean expensive operation to draw the shadow.  Its because of the gradient and the compositing of all the layers together to make the final screen.

Comment: Yes, heavy I mean slow, but VERY slow to the point of UIView creep to load. Seems to be carrying the world! hehehe Is there a solution to that ? or PNG is the solution "elegant" to that... rsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following function to give shadow to any control like, button, label, textfield or view just pass that control to this function

```
    - (void)setShadowOnView:(UIView)aView
    {
        CALayer *layer = aView.layer;
        layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];//change is to set color of shadow
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.f;//change is to set alpha of shadow
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2.5f, 0.f);//change is to set size of shadow
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.f;//change is to set radios of shadow
        layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aView.bounds] CGPath];
    }
```

try to set properties as you like and as per your requirement..

Enjoy coding .......

Comment: Work that way! But why function is better than "direct code" ?

Comment: i have made this function for the purpose of reusability. if you write direct code with the same values then also this will give same effect try it.....

Comment: if i write direct, than i will have the problem i told here... but in function no.... that is pretty wired! do you know why ?

Comment: Isn't the problem that perhaps your direct code does not specify the shadow path? I also use the layer shadow approach, and as soon as a shadow is applies with the default image pixels as path, rendering slows to a halt.

Comment: After playing around with the variables... it seems to be a lot faster because you are defining `layer.shadowPath` it doesn't have to calculate the shadow at runtime.

Comment: Another option if you desperately need to have a dynamic path is to create a view that's aligned / has it's bounds set to the view you need a shadow on and send it behind that view... Having a view with a lot of subviews is the cause.