# Shadow lagging the user interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shadow, quartz-core

I have around 15 views for which I apply QuartzCore shadow like this:

```
for button in buttonsArray {
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.4, height: 1.2)
}
```

When I have a lot of this shadow in 1 view(like in this example) it really starts to slow and lag the user interface.
How can I fix it, or what other alternatives do I have? Thanks!

Comment: @holex not on the simulator, I have only tested it on an iOS 8 iPhone 5, but I think it lags on all devices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why add shadow to any layer is too heavy? Using QuartzCore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197121/why-add-shadow-to-any-layer-is-too-heavy-using-quartzcore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the WWDC 2014 video 'Advanced Graphics and Animations for iOS Apps'.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

35:50 in ... it talks about why using that type of code to generate a shadow causes extra off screen passes for the GPU as it figures out the shape of the shadow.

The suggested solution is to also use the `shadowPath` property on the layer if you already know the shape of the shadow...

It's a great video to watch.

Comment: `shadowPath` is **the** way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your buttons look, one idea would be to use a background image for the buttons that includes the shadow, instead of adding the shadow in code. You can also use `resizableImageWithCapInsets` to make for the various possible sizes of your buttons.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 6, 16, 6);    // change the insets to fit your needs
image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Documentation on resizableImageWithCapInsets can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:

This solution may not be fit for you, depending on how your buttons look. But using images instead of adding the shadow from code should speed up your code.